# Why do we need to deploy a smart contract to swap tokens on Uniswap?

Tags: uniswap

I didn't get why do we need to deploy a smart contract to call a router function? Why not just send a transaction to the router via web3 or ethers?

Comment: You don't need to deploy a smart contract to call functions on the router... Look at the uniswap interface. It makes you call the router directly from a non-contract address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SDK to interact with the contracts without deploying a contract https://docs.uniswap.org/SDK/

Comment: Ok, I can see a big amount of smart contracts with one transfer/swap, I don't know why do we need to create a smart contract.